# Matrix will not work with URL segments to set a row id

Tags: matrix, add-on

I'm trying to do something incredibly simple yet it just won't work and I'm getting frustrated. I have a list of staff members in a Matrix field. Upon selecting a staff member the user is taken to a new template with a detailed bio of that member. I'm using URL segments to pass the row_id of the selected staff member to the bio template but when clicked nothing is displayed. If I manually enter the row_id it works fine which leads me to believe that Matrix does not work with the URL segment variables? Here is the code I'm using:

**Page with list of staff members:**

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="staff"}   
    {staff_members}                     
     <a href="{path='templates/bio/{row_id}'}">
    {/staff_members}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

**Detailed Staff Template**

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="staff"}
    {staff_members row_id="{segment_3}"}
        {staff_bio}
    {/staff_members}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Is this not possible with Matrix or am I missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that {exp:channel:entries} tag tries to treat your row_id in URL as entry_id and hence returning no results.

The solution would be to use dynamic="no" parameter and specify what URL segment contains entry url_title/entry_id

```
{exp:channel:entries dynamic="no" url_title="{segment_2}"}
{staff_members row_id="{segment_3}"}
```